# NextJS app `_next/data` JSON data URLs are showing 404 but when loaded directly in browser json is showing

Tags: javascript, kubernetes, next.js

I have a nextjs (v13) app that is on a self hosted kubernetes cluster. NextJS most of the ajax json data call form _data directory is showing as 404. But when I load those url into my browser I am not getting any 404 error.

I am not sure what is happening as in dev version everything looks perfect. You can find the site here https://sportsdemy.com

I am not sure where to start the debugging. Any hint or direction would be great to have. Just in case I have pasted my nextjs config file below:

```
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
    reactStrictMode: true,
    images: {
        domains: [
            'media.api-sports.io',
            'media-2.api-sports.io',
            'media-3.api-sports.io',
        ],
    },
    experimental: {
        swcMinify: true,
    },
    compiler: {
        styledComponents: true,
    },
    output: 'standalone',
};

module.exports = nextConfig;
```

#### 404 example

[image]

But if you load the url into your browser. You can load the json file just fine. [Click here](https://sportsdemy.com/_next/data/lgSmKzzVjSPr2y95PaCfz/matches/falcons-vs-marimoo/90120.json?slug=falcons-vs-marimoo&matchId=90120)

Comment: please share detail how you have set the service and exposing the application using any ingress or not ?

Comment: When you say 'But when I load those url into my browser I am not getting any 404 error.' - do you mean you don't get the error in your local environment? If that's so it may be the case that in your production environment you have a reverse proxy in front of your Next.js server (nginx or such) that, for some reason, is not allowing _next/data requests to pass. But as @HarshManvar said, we would need more info here to help.

Comment: @Koy What I meant was when I copy the production json URL into browser, and hit enter, i get the json data.

Comment: I have given example as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, looks like this issue was created because I didn't create a volume for `_next/cache` Once I have mapped `_next/cache` into a volume which all containers can share the 404 issue was gone.

If I have more update I will add it here.